# How can I synchronize custom transitions for multiple child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a container UIViewController (DuoContainerController) which contains two child controllers:

HeaderController - contains a label, and can change its height

BodyController - a normal UINavigationController

My goal is to perform custom interactive transitions between controllers in the BodyController, and have the HeaderController animate various properties (in this example height and label text) in sync with the transitions of the BodyController.

Controllers pushed onto the BodyController have a custom transition, which I am currently managing in DuoContainerController. For sake of simplicity, it's just a fade, but I would also like to know how to make individual subviews in each controller do something like transition in from the right when pushing and transition out to the bottom when popping.

I think I need to do something with UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator, but the documentation is light, and I can't find any examples like what I'm trying to do here. It's not clear if it's meant for something like this, or just simple stuff like dismissing a decoration view.

I set up a skeleton project to test out this problem at the following link. It sets up three child controllers in the body, which perform an interactive fade transition.
https://github.com/GoldenJoe/TransitionTest

To recap, I want to do the following:

1. Change the HeaderController's height and text in sync with the child controller transitions.
2. Make the label for the child controllers translate in/out during the transition, rather than just make the entire view fade.
3. Bonus - Any architecture recommendations for delegation and animator implementation would be appreciated.

[image]